# Spring Boot ${} tags not being rendered

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot MVC application, but I can't seem to get ${} tags to render in my views.

As per research, I've added the following dependencies to my POM.XML file, but this didn't help.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Here's the controller I'm calling:

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView applicationRoot() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("app/login");
        mav.addObject("name", "John Doe");

        return mav;
    }

}
```

Here's my view:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="template" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/template" %>

<template:login metaTitle="Intranet Login">
    <h1>Please login</h1>
    <h2>${name}</h2>
</template:login>
```

The template tag

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" dynamic-attributes="dynamicAttributes" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="metaTitle" type="java.lang.String" rtexprvalue="true" required="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>${metaTitle}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <jsp:doBody />
</body>

</html>
```

I'm deploying this project as a war file to Apache TomCat.

Comment: What is your template tag doing...

Comment: Also do you want them rendered or the EL applied?

Comment: I've added the template code to the original question. My aim is to have the metaTitle and the name object passed into the view rendered in the template and the view. I can get this working on plain old Spring MVC, but not on Spring Boot MVC

Comment: Still not clear. Which tag isn't rendering? Both or the title?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, no ${} tags are rendering at all. So both ${name} and ${metaTitle} are not being rendered. Instead, I see the tags in the output.

Comment: and you are using a war or jar? Deploying or running an embedded server? Please provide some necessary details!

Comment: I've updated the original question. I'm deploying as a war file to TomCat

Comment: Do you accidentally have a web.xml?

Comment: yes, it looks like IntelliJ created one when I created the project. I've deleted it and the problem is resolved. I also found this link which describes a similar issue http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/modelandviews-model-value-is-not-displayed-in-jsp-via-el/

Comment: If your web.xml has an too old version (2.4 or earlier) EL doesn't work.